# Is it good practice to manage view instantiation in a router?

Tags: backbone.js

So this is my first Backbone project and I'm wondering if I'm doing things in the best way. My app basically has two states, one of them displays a search box and the other displays a search box with a table under it. My router has routes for searching and for the initial landing page with just the search view. When the user types in the query the router navigates to the search route and the table view is added to the page. This is my router:

```
app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        '': 'index',
        'search/coords=:address&age=:age&rad=:rad': 'search'
    },

    search: function(address, age, rad){    
        app.statusView || (app.statusView = new app.StatusView());
        app.searchView || (app.searchView = new app.SearchView());
        app.trigger('status:loading');
        app.Practices.fetch({
            reset: false,
            success: function() {
                app.searchView.setElement($('#search-box')).render();
                var searchQuery = new app.SearchQueryModel({age: age, coords: address.split(","), radius: rad});
                if (!app.tableView){
                    app.tableView = new app.TableView({model: searchQuery});
                } else {
                    app.tableView.model = searchQuery;
                    app.tableView.refresh();
                };
            }
        });
        app.trigger('status:clear');
    },

    index: function() {
        app.statusView = new app.StatusView();
        app.searchView = new app.SearchView();
        app.footerView = new app.FooterView();
        app.searchView.setElement($('#search-box')).render();
    }
});
```

As you can see my views are instantiated in the index route and then the same views are used when you search, unless the user is going directly to the search page in which case the views are instantiated there. I'd be surprised if this wasn't very sub-optimal because it seems clumsy to be checking if the view already exists in the search route. Is there a better way of doing things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say its not bad, but there is one better approach.

As for now you router is in charge of hook-up URL with app astatus and also for view and model control. The second may be detached from Router, so you will need Controller abstraction, but Backbone does not provide Controller "from the box".

But this is not the problem, you can use [plugin](https://github.com/artyomtrityak/backbone.controller) or take a look at Controller realization in [Marionette.js](http://marionettejs.com/)

The main idea here is to split responsibilities between app part correctly:

1) **Router** - keeps routes and hook up URL with controller action

2) **Controller** - manage views and models (create, delete, fetch and so on)

3) **View** - listen to model and DOM events and render data

4) **Model** - provide actual data and work with data.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I think a controller is what I need. My application is simple enough that I reckon I could just make my own. One thing I'm confused about is who owns the views. Do I instantiate them just in the scope of the controller and let the controller manage all interaction with them, or do I set them up the way I have right now with having them under the app namespace?

Comment: The rule i follow - if doubt who is responsible for some action - leave it to controller ;) So all interaction with view and model classes should do a controller (instance, fetch, delete, render). Application namespace should be used for global tasks - store common classes and methods and some other stuff witch in use in other app parts.

Answer (score 0):

First of all welcome to Backbone.  It is a lovely framework which can allow you to make things as beautiful or ugly as you'ld like.  Your question is about where view instantiation should be, in terms of good practices.  Of course it seems sort of wrong to do it there as it violates the **Law of Demeter** by handling both url routing and view instantiation.

But the views have to be run from somewhere right?  If not the router then where?

So I have two responses:

1. If your app is simple and you just want to play with backbone then you're probably going to be fine.  A lot of people let single page app frameworks complicate otherwise simple apps.  I'm not trying to be lazy, but where you have it now is the natural beginner's choice in Backbone.  If this is your case then stop here.
2. If you want to use the full power of backbone to custom make a framework then read on.

So my setup is designed to be able to start a new project using some boilerplate functions and create only a few classes which are specific to the new app.  Route handling and all of that kind of thing seems low-level enough to me that it should be just part of some configuration that I don't want to look at often.  The upshot is that my router looks like this:

```
define([
    'autorouter'
], function(AutoRouter){
    var AppRouter = AutoRouter.extend({
        autoRoutes: {
            ":page" : "routeDirect",
            ":page/:object" : "routeDirect",
            ":page/:object/:action" : "routeDirect",
            "": "routeDirect"
        }
    });

    return AppRouter;
});
```

Then for each new project I have a file where I keep the non-default routes, for instance:

```
define(function(require){
   return {
        "schedule" : require('screens/schedule')
      , "logout" : require('screens/logout')
      , "login" : require('screens/login')
      , "create" : require('screens/create')
      , "upload" : require('screens/upload')
      , "select" : require('screens/selection')
      , "inventory" : require('screens/inventory')
      , "describe" : require('screens/description')
   }
});
```

I put each screen into it's own file (using requirejs for the multi-file dependency management).  The extra variables get passed through to the `screen`.

Each `screen` is the brain for a particular user experience and is responsible for loading views and maybe handling some events while that screen is active.

If that seems like an interesting setup then here is how I did it:

For the router itself I use a boilerplate class which I borrowed from [Derick Bailey](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/01/02/reducing-backbone-routers-to-nothing-more-than-configuration/) with some slight modifications:

```
define([
    'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'],
function($, _, Backbone) {
    var AutoRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
      constructor: function(options){
          Backbone.Router.prototype.constructor.call(this, options);
          var that = this;
          that.app = options.app;
          if (this.autoRoutes){
            that.processAutoRoutes(options.app, that.autoRoutes);
          }
      },

      processAutoRoutes: function(app, autoRoutes){
          var method, methodName;
          var route, routesLength;
          var routes = [];
          var router = this;

          for(route in autoRoutes){
            routes.unshift([route, autoRoutes[route]]);
          }

          routesLength = routes.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < routesLength; i++){
            route = routes[i][0];
            methodName = routes[i][1];
            method = app[methodName];
            router.route(route, methodName, method);
          }
      }
    });

    return AutoRouter;
});
```

I never have to look at it, but I do need to pass it an app instance.  For example:

```
this.appRouter = new AppRouter({app : this});
```

Finally my route direction function:

```
define(function(require){

   var pathParser = function(path){
     return Array.prototype.slice.call(path);
   }

   var pathApply = function(path, routes, context){
     var pathArray = pathParser(path);
     var primary = pathArray[0];
     if (routes.hasOwnProperty(primary)){
         routes[primary].apply(context, pathArray.slice(1));
     } else {
         routes["default"].apply(context, pathArray.slice(1));
     }
   }

   return function(path){
     //NOTE PLEASE that this references AutoRouter
     //Which has an app property
     var oApp = this.app;
     var pathRoutes = _.extend(require('urls'), {
       "default" : require('screens/default')
     });
     pathApply(arguments, pathRoutes, oApp);
   };
});
```

So, did I make things better?  Well if you're doing something very simple with just a screen or two, then you certainly don't want to build this sort of setup from scratch.  But if you're like me, and you want to be able to quickly produce new projects then having some boilerplate like the two classes above allows for one JSON object to tell the app which routes I should send to which screens.  Then I can have all of the logic in the appropriate places, allowing separation of concerns.  Which is why I think Backbone is so pleasant.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your problem is that you are triggering a route each time you are hitting search.

If this is how you are doing it, then use view events hash (used to capture and handle events that happen in a view) for search.Don't use routes. Define an events hash in the view and have a callback to handle the search.

```js
var myAppEventBus = _.extend({},Backbone.Events);

var myAppController = {

  function : search(options) {
    // create an instance of the collection and do a fetch call passing the 
    // search parameters to it.
  
    var searchResultsCollection = new SearchResultsCollection();
  
    // pass search criteria, the success and error callbacks to the fetch
    // method.
    var that = this;
    searchResultsCollection.fetch(
      {
        data:that.options,
        success : function() {
            // Pass the fetched collection object in the trigger call so that
            // it can be
            // received at the event handler call back
            var options = {
              "searchResultsCollection" : that.searchResultsCollection;
            };
            myAppEventBus.trigger("search_event_triggered",options);
     
        },
        error : function() {
          // do the error handling here.
        }
      }
    );
    
     }
};

// Application Router.

var MyAppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes : {
    'search/coords=:address&age=:age&rad=:rad': 'search'
  },
  
  search : function(searchParams) {
    // Fetch the query parameters and pass it to the view.
    
    var routeSearchExists = false;
    var searchOptions = {};
    var options = {};
    
    if(searchParams) {
      routeSearchExists = true;
      // If search params exist split and set them accordingly in
      // the searchOptions object.
      
      options.searchOptions = searchOptions;
    }
    
    // Create and render the search view. Pass the searchOptions
    var searchView = new SearchView(options);
    searchView.render();
    
    // Create and render an instance of the search results view.
    var searchResultsView = new SearchResultsView();
    searchResultsView.render();
    
    // If there are search parameters from the route, then do a search.
    if(routeSearchExists) {
      searchView.search();
    }
  }
  

});

// The main view that contains the search component and a container(eg: div) 
// for the search results.
var SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el : "#root_container",
  
  searchOptions : null,
  
  initialize : function(options) {
    // Intialize data required for rendering the view here.
    // When the user searches for data thru routes, it comes down in the 
    // options hash which can then be passed on to the controller.
    if(options.searchOptions) {
      this.searchOptions = options.searchOptions;    
    }
  },
  
  events : {
    "search #search_lnk":"initSearch"
  },
  
  initSearch : function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var searchOptions = {};
    // Fetch the search fields from the form and build the search options.
    myAppController.search(searchOptions);
    
  },
  
  search : function() {
    if(this.searchOptions) {
       myAppController.search(searchOptions);
    }
  }
  
});

// The view to display the search results.
var SearchResultsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  
  
  searchResultsCollection : null;
  
  initialize : function(options) {
    
    // Handling the triggered search event.
    myAppEventBus.on("search_event_triggered",this.render,this);
  },
  
  
  render : function(options) {
    //search results collection is passed as a property in options object.
    if(options.searchResultsCollection)
       //Render your view.
    else
      // Do it the default way of rendering.
      
  }
});
```

1. SearchView is the root view that contains the search component and a container like div to hold the search results.
2. SearchResultsView displays the result of a search.
3. When search option is clicked, the event callback (initSearch) gets the entered search data.
4. The search method on myAppController object is invoked and the search query is passed.
5. An instance of the search collection is created and fetch is invoked passing it the search query and also the success and error callback.
6. On success, a custom backbone event is triggered along with the fetched collection.
7. The callback(render method in SearchResultsView) for this event is invoked.
8. The callback renders the results of the search.
9. When loading in the router an instance for both the views can be created(the results view will be empty) and attached to the dom.
10. If you wish to search by multiple query strings at the url then I would suggest you to use the following route.
    search?*queryString.
11. In the route callback make a call to a utility function the splits the querystring and returns you a search object and pass on the search string to the view.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I accepted it because it seemed like what I needed but I'm just trying to implement something similar and realized that I think I need routes... I want the user to be able to do a search via the address, like if they go to site.com/search#q=test it searches for that parameter. I don't see how your method facilitates that?

Comment: I have updated the above answer so that it handles search string from route. This can now handle both route searches and user triggered view searches. The change was only in the router callback and added an extra method in the SearchView which just delegates the search to the controller. If the search exists in the route, this method is invoked after the views have been created.

Comment: Ah cool, thanks for that. I've done something similar but slightly different. My search route calls a controller method to make the views, then calls the controller search method which renders and calls the appropriate method on each view, so all model-view interaction is done by the controller. The router just tells the controller what to do. I think my confusion was just caused by a lack of a controller. Everything seems to work together much better now.